# Azure CosmosDb UpsertDocumentAsync committed vs propagated

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I have two endpoints exposed to a client, one that creates a CosmosDb document, and one that reads that same document. Perhaps 2-3 times out of hundreds, I will get an exception from the second endpoint, because the client is trying to access a document that doesn't exist.

I can see from the logs that the first endpoint (create document) gets called, returns a success code, then the second endpoint gets called, but the document isn't actually created until 45-60 seconds after the initial endpoint call.

I suspect that the create document operation is completing successfully, but maybe the data is not being committed right away? Or maybe it's not being propagated right away?

Are there any Upsert return values I should be analyzing?

Comment: What’s the consistency level defined on your account?

Comment: @GauravMantri Default (session)